# Xamarin iOS : How to dispose avplayerlayer when app has gone in background?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

When i play a video in my application and put app into background mode and use another application like any kind of messenger app than messenger typing got hanged. Provide me any way out. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Within your app's delegate methods, you can track the state transitions of your application.

In your `UIApplicationDelegate` (`AppDelegate` class in a default template application), there is a `DidEnterBackground` method that will be called when you app is moved to the background...

```
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
{
  // You have 5 seconds to preform your cleanup, disable OpenGL, etc...
}
```

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the system by calling begin​Background​Task(expiration​Handler:​). In practice, you should return from application​Did​Enter​Background(_:​) as quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs out your app is terminated and purged from memory.

re: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground